# azure, add provider by arm template

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

Is there a way to allow resource providers to be provisioned by users inside an ARM template? I can currently only see a way to do so by PowerShell or going to the subscription directly.

Comment: When you say PowerShell, are you referring to Register-AzureRmResourceProvider? During execution of ARM template, ARM will automatically register the subscription with all resource providers for resource types that exist in the template.

Comment: For automatic resource provider registering, the user or service principal performing the deployment would need the Contributor or Owner roles, which include the `/register/action` operation. In more restrictive environments, the user or service principal roles may be scoped down to specific resource types.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my knowledge, you could not use template to register provider.

> I can currently only see a way to do so by PowerShell or going to the
>   subscription directly.

You also could use Azure CLI to register provider.

```
az provider register --namespace Microsoft.Batch
```

More information please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-supported-services).

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Answer (score -1):

You can refer a following link to register using ARM Portal

https://www.dotnetpiper.com/2020/05/resource-provider-registration-using.html

Comment: And thats a 'template'?