# Container App or Container App Environment ARM Template

Tags: azure-aks, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-container-apps

I am trying to create a container app using ARM template.
The container app is within a VNet and ingress connection is also limited to VNet.
I downloaded the template for automation from portal and it has this in template

```
{
    "name": "[parameters('environmentName')]",
    "location": "[parameters('location')]",
    "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/', parameters('workspaceName'))]",
        "Microsoft.Resources/deployments/newInfrastructureSubnetTemplate"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "internalLoadBalancerEnabled": false,
        "appLogsConfiguration": {
            "destination": "log-analytics",
            "logAnalyticsConfiguration": {
                "customerId": "[reference(concat('Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/', parameters('workspaceName')), '2020-08-01').customerId]",
                "sharedKey": "[listKeys(concat('Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/', parameters('workspaceName')), '2020-08-01').primarySharedKey]"
            }
        },
        "vnetConfiguration": {
            "infrastructureSubnetId": "/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<resource-group-name>/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/containerapps-vnet/subnets/containerapps-subnet-0",
            "internal": true
        },
        "zoneRedundant": false
    },
    "apiVersion": "2022-03-01",
    "type": "Microsoft.App/managedEnvironments"
}
```

But this fails with an error because of failure due to managed cluster.

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment : 3:11:14 PM - The deployment 'template' failed with error(s). Showing 1 out of 1 error(s).
Status Message: Managed environment failed to initialize due to managed clusters failed. (Code:OperationFailed)
CorrelationId: <correlation-id>
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName dhapi-ml -TemplateFi ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet
```

VNet, subnet and log-analytics workspace are also created using the same template as below for your reference.

```
{
    "apiVersion": "2020-08-01",
    "name": "[parameters('workspaceName')]",
    "type": "Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces",
    "location": "[parameters('workspaceLocation')]",
    "dependsOn": [],
    "properties": {
        "sku": {
            "name": "PerGB2018"
        },
        "retentionInDays": 30,
        "workspaceCapping": {}
    }
},
{
    "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
    "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
    "name": "newInfrastructureSubnetTemplate",
    "resourceGroup": "<resource-group-name>",
    "subscriptionId": "<subscription-id>",
    "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "template": {
            "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
            "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
            "parameters": {},
            "variables": {},
            "resources": [
                {
                    "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets",
                    "apiVersion": "2020-07-01",
                    "name": "containerapps-vnet/containerapps-subnet-0",
                    "properties": {
                        "delegations": [],
                        "serviceEndpoints": [],
                        "addressPrefix": "10.0.0.0/23"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', 'containerapps-vnet')]"
    ]
},
{
    "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
    "apiVersion": "2020-07-01",
    "location": "eastus",
    "name": "containerapps-vnet",
    "properties": {
        "addressSpace": {
            "addressPrefixes": [
                "10.0.0.0/16"
            ]
        },
        "subnets": []
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the problem repeatedly?

Comment: @JJ. yes, it's coming up repeatedly.

Comment: Please share correlationId of the recent failure

Comment: The error you're getting is worthless, and I got it too. You're using 10.0.0.0/23 as infrastructure subnet. By default, the 10.0.0.0/16 range is used by Azure Container Apps for environment infrastructure components. This is probably causing the conflict.

Comment: @JJ. Correlation Id: 1b3c0b0d-3e7b-4367-9fc9-1403bb1acb15

Comment: @Ankur Have a look at https://www.pimwiddershoven.nl/entry/azure-container-apps-and-azure-container-registry-with-bring-your-own-vnet. It is an example in Bicep so you should translate it to ARM when you can't or don't want to use Bicep. This is a working example. Disclaimer: it is my blog

Comment: @PiWi Even in your blog, you have the same infra subnet 10.0.0.0/23 and address prefix in VNet as 10.10.0.0/16. The only difference I can see is how you are creating subnet in the same resource item as VNet but I have a different item for subnet to be created in VNet. 
10.0.0.0/23 is the minimum address space required for Container Apps right? So this should work I guess. 
PS: Your blog is very nice. Thank you very much.

Comment: In the blog 10.10.x.x is used and not the 10.0.x.x range. You can change the default CIDR range to something else if you want to use 10.0.0.0/23 instead. Just curious if this solves your problem.

Comment: @Ankur The correlation id '1b3c0b0d-3e7b-4367-9fc9-1403bb1acb15' is the initial request. Could you try again and share the latest one. Thanks.

Comment: Additionally, confirm your subscription is registered for `Microsoft.ContainerService` RP

Comment: @PiWi I have 10.0.0.0/23 in one of my personal subscription and running a container app. there but in this subscription it fails at creating a managed environment when running through ARM. On my personal subscription I have created this manually using Azure Portal.

Comment: @JJ. Damn, yeah the subscription is not registered for service. Is there any way I can register it with ARM template. (Not through Azure Portal or CLI)

Comment: Only workaround is to refer the resource type from template. ARM will automatically register.

Comment: I had to remove NAT from my 10.0.0.0/23 subnet as it ate away available address space. The deployment failed with the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subscription was not registered to use `Microsoft.ContainerService`
I just registered it from portal or you can use powershell/azcli to do it.
And then it worked to create the container app.

Answer (score 0):

> The subscription is not registered for service. Is there any way I
> can register it with ARM template. (Not through Azure Portal or CLI) .

Thank you @*Shui shengbao* As mentioned [***here***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48014451/azure-add-provider-by-arm-template#:%7E:text=During%20execution%20of%20ARM%20template,that%20exist%20in%20the%20template.),  and after my research posting the same as an answer so that it will be beneficial for other members for similar issue.

> ***It seems , There is no such way to register resource provider through***
> ***ARM Template. You can use the manual registration ,if the resource***
> ***provider is not registered in your subscription.***

Alternatively, we can use the PowerShell to register resource provider by using  below command (e.g):-

```
Register-AzResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.ContainerService
```

As its already registered in our subscription ,it might be showing you ***registering*** but you can do operations to deploy resources.

[image]

For more information please refer this **MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION**| [***Register resource provider***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/resource-providers-and-types) .